# Which rate should we call spinOnce()

Tags: ros-kinetic, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using Qt GUI and a timer in a slot to call spinOnce() periodically. I would like to ask at which rate should I call this function spinOnce()?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390302/which-rate-should-we-call-spinonce()/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2021-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm using Qt GUI and a timer in a slot to call spinOnce() periodically. I would like to ask at which rate should I call this function spinOnce()?

At a minimum at the lowest rate you expect messages to come in / events to be scheduled -- if you care about delays.

Ideally at a much higher rate, as delaying processing the event queue (ie: calling `spinOnce()`) will introduce artificial delays in your event processing.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2